# Turn list with strings in list with raw strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, rawstring

I'm working on a project in order to learn and develop my code capabilities with Python 3. In this project I need raw strings with paths.

**Example:**

```
rPaths = [r"Path to the app", r"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MAGIX\\MP3 deluxe 19\\MP3deluxe.exe", r"F:\\VLC\\vlc.exe"]
```

I also need this to be achieved from another list that contains only normal lists:

```
Paths = ["Path to the app", "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MAGIX\\MP3 deluxe 19\\MP3deluxe.exe", "F:\\VLC\\vlc.exe"]
```

In order to achieve that I tried the following:

```
rPaths1 = "%r"%Paths

rPaths2 = [re.compile(p) for p in Paths]

rPaths3 = ["%r"%p for p in Paths]
```

To which the results weren't the desired:

```
>>>print(Paths)
['Path to the app', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MAGIX\\MP3 deluxe 19\\MP3deluxe.exe', 'F:\\VLC\\vlc.exe']

>>>print(rPaths)
['Path to the app', 'C:\\\\Program Files (x86)\\\\MAGIX\\\\MP3 deluxe 19\\\\MP3deluxe.exe', 'F:\\\\VLC\\\\vlc.exe']

>>>print(rPaths1)
['Path to the app', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MAGIX\\MP3 deluxe 19\\MP3deluxe.exe', 'F:\\VLC\\vlc.exe']

>>>print(rPaths2)
[re.compile('Path to the app'), re.compile('C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MAGIX\\MP3 deluxe 19\\MP3deluxe.exe'), re.compile('F:\\VLC\\vlc.exe')]

>>>print(rPaths3)
["'Path to the app'", "'C:\\\\Program Files (x86)\\\\MAGIX\\\\MP3 deluxe 19\\\\MP3deluxe.exe'", "'F:\\\\VLC\\\\vlc.exe'"]
```

Can anyone help me?

I would prefer not to import anything.

Comment: Note that raw strings only exist in source code. Once your program is executing, raw strings are just strings. Raw strings are just an easier way to write strings that contain backslashes in your Python file, not a different kind of string. And beware that printing a list of strings will print the `repr` of the strings in the list, whereas printing the string itself will print the `str`, which can be different if the string contains literal backslashes.

Comment: 'raw strings' once evaluated, are just strings. There is no special object that is a raw string. No further 'conversion' is necessary. The problem you have is that you are using backslash escapes `\\ ` in a raw string. When using raw strings, the `\\ ` is treated as literal. Then, the escaped version (as shown in the repr) looks like `\\\\ ` --

Comment: I know they are interpreted in the same way.
I could easily change all \\ to \\\\.

But, that's not the goal. The is to turn a list of strings to a list with strings that are interpreted as raw strings, so that I don't (nor the user) have to change the \\ to \\\\. Manually or inside the code.

@sytech

Comment: I do not understand what you're trying to obtain.
Can you please provide a [mcve]

Comment: @Pitto I will try.
Provided a list 'list = ["\a", "\b", "\c"]' I'm trying to have so code that creates another list with the same elements but interpreting them as raw strings 'rlist = [r"\a", r"\b", "\c"]'

The post shows some ways that I tried without success to use to achieve the goal.

It could be solved changing the \ to \\. However this is not intended.

Comment: If you need the \ character to be shown you need to escape it (https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html) using another \

Comment: @Pitto If the \ character is inside a raw string it doesn't need to be escaped with another \

Answer (score 1):

Raw strings are just strings. The paths can be used the same way, as long as they have the right characters in them.

```
>>> raw_strings = [r'Paths', r'C:\Program Files\Something']
>>> non_raw_strings = ['Paths', 'C:\\Program Files\\Something']
>>> raw_strings == non_raw_strings
True
>>> raw_strings[1]
'C:\\Program Files\\Something'
>>> print(raw_strings[1])
C:\Program Files\Something
```

However, if you double the backslashes *and* use a raw string, you get a different string:

```
>>> r'C:\Program Files\Something' == r'C:\\Program Files\\Something'
False
```

Part of what may be confusing you is that `print`ing a `list` object will use `repr` to format the items in a list, and the interactive Python prompt will also use `repr` to format strings. This means that a string that contains a single backslash may *look* like it contains two backslashes. But don't be fooled:

```
>>> one_backslash_char = '\\'
>>> len(one_backslash_char)
1
>>> one_backslash_char
'\\'
>>> print(one_backslash_char)
\
>>> list_containing_string = [one_backslash_char]
>>> print(list_containing_string)
['\\']
>>> list_containing_string[0]
'\\'
>>> print(list_containing_string[0])
\
```

If your goal is to use the string with a regular expression, and you want to turn characters that are meaningful for regex syntax (e.g. `\`) into a form that will regex match the corresponding literal (e.g. you have `\`, you want to match `\`, so the string needs to contain `\\`), then the function you want is [`re.escape(string)`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/re.html#re.escape) which does exactly this.

Comment: I know strings and raw strings are the same.
That's not the problem.

I want to use the path as it really is. Not changimg the backslashs. It can be achieved by having the paths as raw strings or by having the backslashs doubled.
I don't wish to double the backslashs. My question is: is it possible to put the "r" before every string in a list? If yes, how?

Comment: I know strings and raw strings are the same. That's not the problem. I want to use the path as it really is. Not changimg the backslashs. It can be achieved by having the paths as raw strings or by having the backslashs doubled. I don't wish to double the backslashs. My question is: is it possible to put the "r" before every string in a list? If yes, how?
I know that they may look the same. I understand that. But that's not the case. Even when ii is not printed, when it is used further in the code it does not work, due to the fact that the backslashes aren't escaped.

Comment: No. The grammar of Python is parsed before your code even begins to execute. Thus if you don't have an `r` prefix, any escapes in the strings are parsed into whatever characters they form (and/or errors may be generated) before the string objects are ever created in the first place.

Comment: @user460647: If your goal is to use this string with a regular expression, then perhaps `re.escape()` is what you're looking for? See my edited answer.

Comment: I just tried re.escape and it didn't work in the way I intended. Neither when printing nor when using it further in the code.
The code works when I double the backslashes or when I manually plave the r before the strings.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: You really need to create a [mcve]. Show *exactly* what you're doing and *exactly* how it's failing. "It didn't work in the way I intended" doesn't help because I still have no idea what you intend.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this clear, you want to match a certain path using `re.compile`, but that isn't how it works. According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#module-contents), you should try this:

```
prog = re.compile(pattern)
result = prog.match(string)
```

In your case, I'd try

```
for pattern in rPaths:
    prog = re.compile(pattern)
    rPaths2 = [prog.match(string) for string in Paths]
```

Again, not 100% sure of what your question really is. Does this help?

Comment: I just tried and the result wasn't the expected.
Sorry for not making myself clear.

what I want is to turn strings (ex.: "\a", "\b") to raw strings (ex.: r"\a", r"\b").
This is to escape the backslash ("\").
One way that this would work is to escape the backslash with another (ex.: "\\a", "\\b"). This could be easily coded or I could also do this manually every time I insert a path. However this is not the intended. What is intended is to use raw strings, not change backslashes.

There is another thing to have in mind: the strings are inside lists.